# mysql sql: how to cumulate count ? (sum of count)

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to get cumulate number of users registered by date

Here is my mysql sql

```
SELECT MONTH( DATE ) AS `month`, COUNT(userid) 
FROM  `stats` 
WHERE  `userid` = 1
GROUP BY `month`
```

This gives me number of users per month, but does not cumulate them

result:

```
month 1 : 90
month 2 : 50 (it should be 90 + 50)
month 3 : 10 (it should be 90 + 50 + 10)
```

I tried:

```
SELECT month,
       SUM( CNT ) AS CUM_CNT_TILL_NOW
  FROM  (
        SELECT MONTH( DATE ) AS `month`, COUNT(userid) AS CNT
          FROM  `stats` 
         WHERE  `userid` = 1
         GROUP BY `month`
      );
```

and got error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Check the answer I posted...

Comment: I don't think the aforementioned duplicate will help this OP because it doesn't involve aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, there are basically three ways to do a cumulative sum:

- A correlated subquery.
- Inequality joins with aggregation.
- Variables.

The latter is the simplest.  However, because of the way that `group by` works in MySQL, often you need a subquery:

```
SELECT yyyy, mm, cnt,
       (@sum := @sum + cnt) as cume_sum
FROM (SELECT YEAR(DATE) as yyyy, MONTH( DATE ) AS mm, COUNT(userid) AS CNT
      FROM stats
      WHERE userid = 1
      GROUP BY yyyy, mm
     ) ym CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @sum := 0) params
ORDER BY yyyy, mm;
```

Notes:

- This wisely takes the year into account.  That is usually intended when you are accumulating by month.
- The `@sum` variable is defined in the query.  This is a convenience.
- The subquery is needed because sometimes variables do not work as expected with aggregations.
- The subquery has an alias.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT month,
       SUM( CNT ) OVER ( ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING  
                         AND CURRENT ROW 
                        ) AS CUM_CNT_TILL_NOW
  FROM
     (
        SELECT MONTH( DATE ) AS `month`, COUNT(userid) AS CNT
          FROM  `stats` 
         WHERE  `userid` = 1
         GROUP BY `month`
      );
```

Another Solution :-

```
WITH tmp AS 
(
  SELECT MONTH( DATE ) AS `month`, COUNT(userid) AS CNT 
    FROM  `stats` 
   WHERE  `userid` = 1
  GROUP BY `month`
 )
SELECT o.month, o.cnt , RunningTotal = o.cnt + COALESCE(
(
  SELECT SUM(cnt) AS cnt
    FROM tmp i
    WHERE i.month < o.month), 0
)
FROM tmp AS o
ORDER BY o.month;
```

Comment: what is the : ( ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING    AND CURRENT ROW  ) ??? is that a comment ?

Comment: ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING AND CURRENT ROW is a sql syntax where you can perform computation on all the rows before current row.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( ORDER BY month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING AN' at line 2

Comment: BTW, I am using MYSQL

Comment: I added another solution using correlated query. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql, you can make use of session variable. like below:

```
SET @sum = 0;
SELECT MONTH( DATE ) AS `month`, @sum:=@sum+COUNT(userid) as sum
FROM  `stats` 
WHERE  `userid` = 1
GROUP BY `month`;
```

Or else, You will have to join the two tables but that would be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

try with something like:

```
SELECT MONTH(DATE) AS `month`, COUNT(userid) , (SELECT COUNT(userid) 
    FROM  `stats` 
    WHERE  `userid` = 1 AND MONTH(date) <= MONTH(s.date))
FROM  `stats` s
WHERE  `userid` = 1
GROUP BY `month`
```

Thanks jpw for correction

Comment: If you change the `where` clause in the subquery to `WHERE  userid = 1 AND MONTH(DATE) <= MONTH(s.DATE)` your query should produce the expected result.